# NSInteger 1 when multiplied by 0.05f returns 0.0500000007

Tags: objective-c, floating-point

A float problem in iOS when `indexPath.row=1`

```
Float32 value=0.05*indexPath.row;
```

it returns `value=0.0500000007` but it should be `0.05`. How to fix this??

Comment: Just round off to 2 digits after decimal.

Comment: http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-questions-are-endless-on-stackoverflow-com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: The closest IEEE 754 32-bit binary floating point number to 0.05 is 0.0500000007450580596923828125. Multiplying it by 1 is not going to change its value.

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks that really helped! esp. http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to floating point errors.

The easiest way to fix this is just to round the number after multiplying.

You can read more about why this is happening on [this random website I found on Google](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: thanks... even after rounding the float It was still saving 0.0500000007 but i ended up changing the way i needed...